# Format code for a tag

Tags: discussion

According to this: [Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) syntax highlighting can be inferred from the tag(s).  How does a tag get associated with a language?

The tags [azure-ad-b2c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-ad-b2c) and [identity-experience-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/identity-experience-framework) should be associated with XML IMHO.

Where is the master list of the tag-to-associated language(s) mapping?

Comment: [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108)

Comment: Thanks @MikeMcCaughan, that helps but I don't see what is the process to associate a tag w/ language.  Thoughts?

Comment: @spottedmahn Keep reading the question.  It covers it.

Comment: "If you're curious whether a tag has a language hint, any user is capable of checking by visiting that tag's wiki page. The language hint (if any) that is currently being used for that tag will be displayed at the very bottom, below the buttons for the wiki:" Also, towards the end, there's a section titled "If you want a language added"...

Answer (score 1):

From the current version of [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108):

> If the tag doesn't have a highlighting language specified when it should, create a `feature-request` on the per-site meta for your site to request it. (Only moderators can change the highlighting language for a tag.)